# POST request not working while using Alamofire pod in swift2?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7.2

I’m doing a Demo App in `Swift 2` that makes an `HTTP` `POST` request. But don’t understand why my request doesn't hit the server.
I’m using `Alamofire 3.0`, `Xcode 7.2`, `swift 2.0`.
I installed the `Alamofire` pod based on this [link](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#requirements): https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#requirements

And my string is

```
str = "{videos{title,videourl,imageurl}}"
```

Here my code is:

```
Alamofire.request(
    .POST,
    url,
    parameters: Dictionary(),
    encoding: .Custom({
        (convertible, params) in
        let mutableRequest = convertible.URLRequest.copy() as! NSMutableURLRequest
        mutableRequest.setValue("application/graphql", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        mutableRequest.HTTPBody = str.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
        return (mutableRequest, nil)
    }),
    headers: nil
).responseJSON{
    (JSON) -> Void in
        if  JSON.result.value != nil
        {
            print(JSON.result.value)
            self.delegate.successReponse(JSON.result.value!, withType: type)      
        } 
        else
        {   
        }
}
```

When i’m printing the `JSON.result.value`, it’s showing like this:

```
Optional({
    errors = (
        {
        }
    );
})
```

I don’t understand why it is not reaching to the server.

Comment: May be the server is not returning any data?  You should print the http response of the request made in the console and check

Comment: You say "it doesn't hit the server", did you actually check server logs? Is your URL correct?

Comment: @jcaron yes i check the server logs and also my  url works fine in postman.

Comment: is your server url https ?

Answer (score 0):

Have your do it before ? App Transport Security in info.plist.
https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire
Secondly, the parameters 's don't have any things. It should be change your string to Dictionary.

Your can use json to make string to Dictionary.

```
let data = changestring.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)
var dict = NSDictionary()
do{
    //dict = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
    dict = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as! NSDictionary
}
catch{
}

NSLog("this is dict \(dict)")
```

Or you can just past NSDictionary to parameters.

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, "https://httpbin.org/post", parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON)
```

If your want to others method for HTTP POST and GET, this link is Suitable for you: https://github.com/RYANCOAL/swift-with-AFNetworking/blob/master/TestHTTPTests/TestHTTPTests.swift

Manual Validation
Alamofire.validate(contentType: ["application/json"]) can search the value for contentType, by I don't know it can / cannot be set contentType.